# vertex limit, how to load large models?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm using the vertex buffer:

```
    private FloatBuffer     vertexBuffer;

    private float   vertices[] =
                {
                        1.00f,  0.02f, -1.00f,
                        1.00f,  0.02f,  1.00f,
                        -1.00f,  0.02f,  1.00f,
                        -1.00f,  0.02f, -1.00f,
                        1.00f,  2.02f, -1.00f,
                        1.00f,  2.02f,  1.00f,
                        -1.00f,  2.02f,  1.00f,
                        -1.00f,  2.02f, -1.00f
                        ....
                        ....
                };

    private byte indices[] =
        {
                46, 0, 2,
                3, 1, 47,
                44, 2, 4,
                5, 3, 45 
                ...
        }

    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect( vertices.length * 4 );
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()); 
    vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(vertices);        
    vertexBuffer.position( 0 );   

    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length,                 GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indexBuffer);
```

The problem is when I want to define an model, that exceeds 255 vertices, I obviously get a compilation error. What do I have to do to be able to define a model of thousands of vertices?

Error I'm getting:

Error:(609, 26) error: possible loss of precision
required: byte
found:    int

Comment: What error do you get? Also, are you going to hardcode thousands of vertices?

Comment: @emd4600 I updated my answer. I will load them from a file in future, I'm learning openGL and came across this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> private byte indices[]=...
> ```

Don't use `byte` type if you need higher values than 255. OpenGL ES 2.0 supports 8 and 16 bit types for index arrays, so up to 65536 different vertices can be referenced in a single draw call. If you need even more, you need to split it up into several arrays.

Note that lot's of devices might also support 32 bit indices, but that is not required by the spec. It is provided by the [`OES_element_index_uint`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_element_index_uint.txt) extenstion

Answer (score 1):

```
gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indexBuffer);
```

[`GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/opt-pkgs/api/jb/jsr239/javax/microedition/khronos/opengles/GL10.html#GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE) goes from 0 to 255, so as you've said, you can't get a higher index.

But you can use [`GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/opt-pkgs/api/jb/jsr239/javax/microedition/khronos/opengles/GL10.html#GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT) (from 0 to 65535, 2 bytes long) instead.

Then, use a [`IntBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/IntBuffer.html) for the indices instead.

Comment: The OP is using ES 1.x. `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` is only supported in ES 3.0 and later.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that, fixed.

Comment: The buffer type matching `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` would be `ShortBuffer`, not `IntBuffer`.

Comment: But `ShortBuffer` only accepts signed shorts, right? (Sorry, I've never used that one)